# Angular - Using 'title' as @Input

Tags: angular

Using the html attributes `title` as an `@Input()` leads to weird results.

running example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-apd2mf

**Hello.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{title}}{{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() title: string;
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <hello name="{{ name }}" title="Mr. "></hello>
    <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
}
```

**result**
[image]

The issue here is that I see the value of `title` input while hovering anywhere on the heading. I know I can avoid this by using it as

```
<hello name="{{ name }}" [title]="'Mr. '"></hello>
```

But is there a reason why angular is attaching the attribute even though I'm declaring it as an input?

Comment: Yes because i think `title` is an HTML attribute and it is getting confused. You can rename `title` to `nameTitle` to avoid this issue. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_title.asp

Comment: Also, please prefer `[name]="name"`

Comment: Angular isn't doing anything. The browser's HTML parser is seeing a `title` attribute and doing what it's programmed to do; showing a tooltip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To prevent the tooltip from showing up, you can define your custom `title` property as a getter/setter and assign an empty string to the native `title` HTML property in the setter:

```
private _title: string;

@Input() get title(): string {
  return this._title;
}
set title(value: string) {
  this._title = value;
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.title = "";
}

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzrmd4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: `@HostBinding('attr.title') _title = '';` does the trick for me.

Answer (score 4):

At least in Angular 13 you can clear the attribute simply by using `HostBinding` along with a getter:

```
@Input() title = '';

@HostBinding('attr.title') get getTitle(): null {
  return null;
}
```

No setter or `elementRef` references needed. Using null makes sure that the attribute name is removed, not just attribute value.

Answer (score 2):

`title` is a standard html attribute to show `hint` or `tooltip`, when you bind `title` not only you bind `@Input` but also you wired to html title attribute.

The way to fix it using another property name than `title`, something like `text` or `[yourcomponent]Title` like `listTitle`, ...

Answer (score 0):

in angular there are many syntax to interat with component. As @AliF50 said,

`title` will call the html title attribute, where `[title]` will bind to angular input property as you can see [here](https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet).